# How to touch and hold to select text in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to Android and trying to implement a rich editor using Text component of React Native. 
However when I touch the text and hold for a moment, the text was not highlighted and the top bar with selection actions was not shown like what behaves in a webview or other applications.
What am I missing or do I need to implement this feature by myself? If so could you point a direction?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want click-and-hold-to-select-text using a Text component, this feature does not currently exist in React Native for iOS. You probably want to upvote https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-selecting-text-within-text-elements-for-copypaste-etc to suggest Facebook add support for this.

However, I've submitted support for  on Android, as of React 0.30. But React iOS is drawing characters directly to the screen (and not using the native UITextView that supports a selectable property), so it is not supported there, and likely won't be for a long time.

RN 0.39 adds support to copy the entire text field, but does not yet include support for selecting a subset of the text field for copying.

Comment: Dear people-who-downvote-me, care to explain what you don't like about this answer?The native 'text-selection' feature of iOS and Android does not work in the React Native <Text> component, even though the functinoality is supported in the underlying native components. It needs changes to react-native to work. I've poked at this some, but it's not high enough on my priority list to dig through the necessary changes to make it work cross-platform.

Comment: I too would like to know why someone down voted this, when the information is correct. Currently `Text` does not support highlight and copy. It also does not have a native backing for focus to be applied. There are more than a few open issues on github about this. The CURRENT as of 2016-08-29 workaround on this issue, is to use `TextInput` with `editable: false` and apply styles like you would any `Text` component. More information is here: [Github:React-Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2447)

Comment: @MikeLambert thanks for answer .By the way i did not see any issue about this subject so i created a issue on react native project about this question .If you want ,you follow this subject from here: github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13938

Comment: It's not a "bug", it's a "feature that doesn't exist yet", so a github issue is not the correct place for it. I had created one originally, and it was closed in favor of a product pain, which I linked-to-above in my response. They use that to prioritize and triage what features to implement and work on.

Comment: Yes I noticed that it is not a bug but I wonder when it will be integrated so i open this issue.

Answer (score 40):

As of now it is supported by `react-native` as well by adding `props` `selectable={true}`. Also on Android you can change the selected text color with `selectionColor='orange'`.

Example:

```
<Text selectable={true} selectionColor='orange'>You can select me</Text>
```

Comment: I would like to also add that in React Native 0.60.5 when you have the remote debugger ON OR using <TouchableWithoutFeedback> as an ancestor component (not an immediate parent), you may encounter erratic behavior in the "long press" event (sometimes it doesn't get triggered due to setTimeout issues) which can lead you to believe that selectable text in the component is not working. This is what happened to me, so I suggest when developing in debug mode, run your app without the remote debugger to make sure selectable text does not work even in that scenario

Comment: It seems the selectionColor never take action here, why? I have expo snack here: https://snack.expo.dev/@dotku/selectable

Comment: It is working but the selected bit is transparent. I wonder why?

Answer (score 11):

Be careful if the text is nested you should add `selectable` attribute to the top `

```
<Text selectable>
    <Text>
        some selectable text
    </Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: Nice catch. Thank you.

Answer (score -7):

use onPress={this.onPressTitle()} inside Text

and Declare

```
onPressTitle:function(){
/* Your Actions on OnPress */
}
```